# How can I force overflow:scroll when using plugin for responsive-tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I found this plugin when researching stackoverflow on how to design responsive tables:

https://github.com/zurb/responsive-tables

I am using it and it works pretty well for mobile and tablet screen sizes, but it does not for custom sizes (e.g @media(min-width:901px) and (max-width:1280px)) . The problem is my table has many columns and is very wide, so on certain screen sizes such as the above it overflows and the plugin does not allow me to set "overflow:scroll" for sizes above 767px (or rather I can't figure out how).

What I want to do is set overflow for screen sizes above 767px and below 1280px. I hope I am explaining myself well :) Any help will be GREATLY appreciated since I am to the point of banging my head against walls. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to overwrite the overflow value for the screen size you are shooting for is to use firebug to find the selector that is applying overflow:hidden. Then copy that selector inside your media query and put overflow-x:scroll inside it.

For example, if you look at stylesheets/grid.css in the github repo you linked, on line 107 it defines

```
.block-grid { display: block; overflow: hidden; }
```

If you add this to the file after it:

```
@media (min-width:901px) and (max-width:1280px) {
    .block-grid { overflow: scroll; }
}
```

all elements with the block-grid class will on the specified screen size will use scroll bars if needed. They key here is to make sure this is loaded after the css class you are trying to overwrite, because media queries don't add anything to the specificity of a selector. So if multiple media queries apply at the same time and have the same css selector in them, it comes down to which one is found last.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes a lot of sense, however it didn't work. I made sure to write it after the class to be overwritten too. Maybe it is another selector? I am trying to use firebug, it is a new tool for me and I am figuring out how it works. WIll keep at it. Again, many thanks!